# Logback Android does not log on release

Tags: android, file, logging, logback, release

I am using the Logback library to keep logs for my Android application.

I have the xml like below

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package.name/files/logs" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <!-- active log file -->
        <file>${LOG_DIR}/log.txt</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>50MB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>500MB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

In the debug version of the app the logs work properly as expected. But in the release version i noticed that there is no logs folder inside the LOG_DIR.
What is wrong?

Comment: Can you link to a reproduction? Are your Proguard settings preserving the SLF4J calls?

Comment: @tony19 
implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30"i
mplementation "com.github.tony19:logback-android:2.0.0"
Thats the dependecies that i use, but i have not added anything in the Proguard rules. What should i add?